# Missing Google Ad Campigns in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

App Engagement Campaigns that are present in the Google Analytics Interface are not present in BigQuery.

All other campaign data gets transferred to BigQuery.

Is there a specific reason for this behavior in the transfer job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [transfer job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer) only uses the Google Adwords v201809 version of the API.

App Engagement Campaigns were only added in the newer [Google Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration).

You will need to set up a connection the the [new API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start) in order to pull in that type of campaign (as well as a host of other ad types).